# trying to understand this function encryption(message)

Tags: javascript, encryption

This is a function that will encrypt a given sentence into International Morse Code, both the input and out puts will be strings.
Characters are separated by a single space. Words are separated by a triple space.
For example, "HELLO WORLD" should return -> ".... . .-.. .-.. --- .-- --- .-. .-.. -.."

A preloaded object/dictionary/hash called CHAR_TO_MORSE is provided to help convert characters to Morse Code.

However, I don't understand why we need an inner loops in the function?

```
    function encryption(message) {
              var arr = message.split(" ");   //I understand here we split the string into individual words
              for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {     
               arr[i] = arr[i].split("");   //then we use the loop to split the words further into characters?
               for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {  //but we need an inner loop here? what is the purpose of this j loop? is that necessary ? 
                  arr[i][j] = CHAR_TO_MORSE[arr[i][j]]; //can’t we just use arr[i] CHAR_TO_MORSE[arr[i]]...I think I totally lost the logic here...
                }
               arr[i] = arr[i].join(" "); 
              }
              arr = arr.join("   ");


              return arr;
}
```

also,If this solution is not optimal, please suggest a better one.

Comment: If answers like Hogan's are the kind of answer you expected, perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com is more appropriate.

Comment: The inner loop is used to add spaces between Morse codes within a word. You can do this by splitting `message` by `''`, but adding spacing within words and between words needs more code.

Answer (score 3):

You have a sentence.  You make that into an array of words.  You make each word into an array of characters.  Now you have an array of arrays of characters.

Two loops is fine.  You loop over each word and internally you loop over each character.

You still only "hit" each character once so there is no "duplicate".

There are other ways to solve this problem, you could just loop over each character in the original without using split at all.  I'm not sure there is a big advantage to making these arrays -- but it is not "wrong".